# Android google signin button

Tags: android, google-oauth

I am trying to follow google's branding rules for login:

https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines?hl=en

However the sign in button sketch file and images look to be meant for ios and web only.  I know that there is a google signin button:

```
    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

However that is the old style logo.

Should I just make my own for Android or does google have a better answer?

Comment: *However that is the old style logo.* question is which gms version you are using? **edit:** doesn't matter in 8.1.0 logo is still the old one ... solution: make a bug issue maybe they will fix it in the next release of gms library ...

Comment: I did find Android titled buttons in the package provided on the branding page.  However the icons have lines in them and no text.  Not really usable...

Comment: fx: common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png from *ANDROID_SDK\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\drawable-[xh]dpi* or in *ANDROID_SDK\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-base\8.1.0\play-services-base-8.1.0.aa\rres\drawable-[xh]dp*

Comment: @Selvin, I have common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light (old) logo but not common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png.

Comment: Also how would I go about putting text into that image?

Comment: text resources: `res\values[-xx]\base_strings.xml` ... common_signin_button_text[_long]